# How to auto-import csv content into Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher

We are trying to receive a CSV file from frontend and create nodes from the CSV content. How do we get the neo4J to load the CSV code from javascript automatically when we receive a new CSV-file?

Currently we are thinking something like this to receive the file in frontend:

```
import fileUpload from "express-fileupload";
app.use(fileUpload());

//Upload endpoint
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  if(req.files === null){
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No file uploaded'});
  }
  const file = req.files.file;
  file.mv(${__dirname}/client/public/uploads/${file.name}, err => {
    if(err){
      console.error();
      return res.status(500).send(err);
    }
    res.json({ fileName: file.name, filePath: `/uploads/${file.name}`});
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options for importing data from a CSV file.

This [CSV import guide](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/) is a good intro.

If you want to import (using the Cypher `LOAD CVS` approach) from within your Javascript program, you should also read up on the official [Drivers](https://neo4j.com/developer/language-guides/).